# pip not installing non .py files (even though they're packaged in wheel)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm successfully packaging my application (`wheel`) to include all my non-python files in it as well. I did this via the `MANIFEST.in` file where I do:

```
include path/to/sql/files/*.sql
```

This works, because after running

```
python setup.py clean sdist
```

I get a `my-app.tar.gz`. Unpacking this `tar` then shows me all the files, including my `.sql` ones. So far so good.

However, when doing a `pip install` from our `Nexus` repository, only the python files show up (even though a manual download from `Nexus` of the `tar` contains everything).

Do I need to change anything in my `setup.py`? I thought the `MANIFEST` file was enough?

Here is all relevant info from my `setup.py`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="my_app",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to include

```
include_package_data=True,
```

in my `setup.py`.

Makes the usage of `MANIFEST.in` a little less attractive now in my opinion.